# Unknown error :Xcode showing "_method_name" referenced from: class_name.o

Tags: ios, header

I am getting strange error thrown by xcode 4.6 .

error is : ---> "_aucodec_list", referenced from:

where "aucodec_list" is name of function from one of the header that I already included in my project.

EDIT : Complete error

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_aucodec_list", referenced from:
      -[ViewController initSIP] in ViewController.o
  "_aufilt_list", referenced from:
      -[ViewController initSIP] in ViewController.o
  "_conf_modules", referenced from:
      -[ViewController initSIP] in ViewController.o
  "_conf_path_set", referenced from:
      -[ViewController initSIP] in ViewController.o
  "_configure", referenced from:
      -[ViewController initSIP] in ViewController.o
  "_libre_close", referenced from:
      -[ViewController deregisterSIP] in ViewController.o
  "_libre_init", referenced from:
      -[ViewController initSIP] in ViewController.o
  "_list_count", referenced from:
      -[ViewController initSIP] in ViewController.o
  "_mem_debug", referenced from:
      -[ViewController deregisterSIP] in ViewController.o
  "_mod_close", referenced from:
      -[ViewController deregisterSIP] in ViewController.o
  "_mod_init", referenced from:
      -[ViewController initSIP] in ViewController.o
  "_net_close", referenced from:
      -[ViewController deregisterSIP] in ViewController.o
  "_net_init", referenced from:
      -[ViewController initSIP] in ViewController.o
  "_pl_set_str", referenced from:
      -[ViewController initSIP] in ViewController.o
  "_play_close", referenced from:
      -[ViewController deregisterSIP] in ViewController.o
  "_re_main", referenced from:
      -[ViewController initSIP] in ViewController.o
  "_tmr_debug", referenced from:
      -[ViewController deregisterSIP] in ViewController.o
  "_ua_add", referenced from:
      -[ViewController initSIP] in ViewController.o
  "_ua_answer", referenced from:
      -[ViewController answerBtnTouch:] in ViewController.o
  "_ua_close", referenced from:
      -[ViewController deregisterSIP] in ViewController.o
  "_ua_connect", referenced from:
      -[ViewController callBtnTouch:] in ViewController.o
  "_ua_cur", referenced from:
      -[ViewController callBtnTouch:] in ViewController.o
      -[ViewController answerBtnTouch:] in ViewController.o
      -[ViewController endBtnTouch:] in ViewController.o
      -[ViewController sendBtnTouch:] in ViewController.o
  "_ua_hangup", referenced from:
      -[ViewController endBtnTouch:] in ViewController.o
  "_ua_im_send", referenced from:
      -[ViewController sendBtnTouch:] in ViewController.o
  "_ua_init", referenced from:
      -[ViewController initSIP] in ViewController.o
  "_ua_start_all", referenced from:
      -[ViewController initSIP] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am just unable to figure out the cause of error 
Can any help in this  ...

Thnx in advance

Paggy 123

Comment: Can you post the exact error.

Comment: Post the whole error.

Comment: It would be good if you could include the full error, but it sounds like a linking error. You will get that if the source or library of the `aucodec_list` function has not been included in your target. If you go to "Target" - "Build Settings", you can either include the .m file(s) for the aucodec functions in the "Compile Sources" section, or include the library in the the "[Link Binary with Libraries](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html)" section.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this problem is that the file that implements the `aucodec_list` is not being compiled with your target. Check that this box

[image]

has your target checked off, or that the file is in the `Build Phases->Compile Sources` section of your target.

Comment: there is nthing like check box in "compile sources" option ... in this we can add the .m files .... but in my case the function are just the declarations . i.e they declared in headers only there is no .m available for corressponding .h file

Comment: Well that's the problem. Your program looks for the implementation of those methods when you call them, but if you' don't implement them the program will crash.